# Amazon CloudFront + Adobe FMS Stack Max Concurrent Users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, flash-media-server

I have been using Wowza on EC2 and now trying to use FMS Stack in AWS with CloudFront Distribution.

So far I managed to setup a live streaming using m1.large FMS Stack + CloudFront Distribution.

The question :
1) M1.Large FMS have a limit of 1000 concurrent RTMFP users, but since I'm using AWS Cloudfront, can my FMS stack serve more than 1000 concurrent users ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in an HTTP Live Streaming setup with CloudFront you should expect a number of concurrent users on the origin close to the number or [CloudFront Edge Locations](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/globalinfrastructure) (about 40 as per today).

This number should not grow with the actual users watching the live stream because the content is cached in the Edge Locations for further access.